# confused with the design of servlet

Tags: java, servlets, web-applications

I want to create servlet which receive data in Json format and store data in the database. When i send data to servlet through http request, it will establish connection with table, create table, and store the data. The code to create connection and table has to be done only for the first time. I am not able to come up with design of code which create connection and table for the first time and store data into rows for the rest of the time

My code is as follows :-

```
public class Master extends 
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    handle(request, response);
}

private void handle(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    if ( req.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("POST")) {
        try {
            String jsonString = extractJsonBody()

           /* code for connection with database
            create table
            store the data */

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Json in bad format");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Start here:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/

Comment: You probably don't want your application to create the DB schema, it's normally done by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> you can use the init method of servlet for connection and table
>   creation with a condition check if table doesn't exist in database.

```
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException { // Store the ServletConfig object and log the initialization 
super.init(config);`` 
// create the database connection and table creation with condition if 
//table do not exist in DB
 }
```

Comment: Is it possible to execute some code when we start the server, before making any POST/Get request to the servlet

Answer (score 0):

You can use Singleton design pattern to create database and table creations.

See below example to create database using singleton pattern

```
public class DataBaseConnector {
    private static DataBaseConnector dbConnector = new DataBaseConnector();

    private Connection dbConnection;

    private DataBaseConnector() {        
        // create database connection here 
    }

    public static DataBaseConnector getInstance() {
        if(dbConnector == null) {
            dbConnector = new DataBaseConnector();
        }
        return dbConnector;
    }

    public Connection getDbConnection() {
        return dbConnection;
    }
}
```

Creating database schema using application is not a good practice. Use separate scripts for that.